# Unhandled exception in c#, Destination array is not long enough to copy all the items in the collection

Tags: c#

I am `c#` beginner and trying to read a binary file to calculate the `frequency` of the `symbols` inside the `binary file`. (Frequency is the number of time the symbols repeats).

In my first step I took I kept the `data type` of `"symbol"` read as `"int"` and **code worked fine.**
But now I wanted to make this symbol of **`generic type`** (I mean `<T>` type).

The code compiles with out any error in ubantu terminal.

But when I execute using `"mono filename.exe BinaryFile.bin"` This binary file is read at `sole argument`. Please see at last that how i got this Binary file **toto.bin.**

The error is :

```
hp@ubuntu:~/Desktop/Internship_Xav/templatescplus$ mono test.exe toto.bin 

Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: Destination array is not long enough to copy all the items in the collection. Check array index and length.
  at System.BitConverter.PutBytes (System.Byte* dst, System.Byte[] src, Int32 start_index, Int32 count) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.BitConverter.ToInt64 (System.Byte[] value, Int32 startIndex) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at shekhar_final_version_Csharp.Huffman`1[System.Int64]..ctor (System.String[] args, System.Func`3 converter) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at shekhar_final_version_Csharp.MyClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.ArgumentException: Destination array is not long enough to copy all the items in the collection. Check array index and length.
  at System.BitConverter.PutBytes (System.Byte* dst, System.Byte[] src, Int32 start_index, Int32 count) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.BitConverter.ToInt64 (System.Byte[] value, Int32 startIndex) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at shekhar_final_version_Csharp.Huffman`1[System.Int64]..ctor (System.String[] args, System.Func`3 converter) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at shekhar_final_version_Csharp.MyClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
hp@ubuntu:~/Desktop/
```

My full code to do so is (narrowed code):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Final 
{
    public class A < T > where T: struct, IComparable < T > , IEquatable < T > 
    {
        public class Node 
        {
            public T symbol;
            public Node next;
            public int freq;
        } public Node Front;

        public A(string[] args, Func < byte[], int, T > converter) 
        {    
            int size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof (T));
            Front = null;
            using(var stream = new BinaryReader(System.IO.File.OpenRead(args[0]))) 
            {   
                while (stream.BaseStream.Position < stream.BaseStream.Length) 
                {   
                    byte[] bytes = stream.ReadBytes(size);   
                    T processingValue = converter(bytes, 0);  

                    Node pt, temp;
                    pt = Front;

                    while (pt != null) 
                    {   Console.WriteLine("check1");
                        if (pt.symbol.Equals(processingValue)) 
                        {
                            pt.freq++;
                            break;
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("Symbol : {0}  frequency is : {1}", pt.symbol, pt.freq);
                        temp = pt;
                        pt = pt.next;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }    //////////////////////////////////////////////////
    public class MyClass 
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args) 
        {
            A < long > ObjSym = new A < long > (args, BitConverter.ToInt64);
        }
    }
}
```

I think the problem is created while creating object of type Huffman in    `public class MyClass`. Could some one please help me how to get a rid of this problem by giving a solution (any piece of code would be highly appreciated)? Thanks.

Comment: Please narrow down your code to the parts you think are relevant to the problem.

Comment: @opd thanks for pointing i have just done that :)

Comment: General note: try not to do too much work in the constructor. Also, command-line variables (`args`) should be parsed in `Main`. If you know in advance that `args[0]` is a file name, then `Huffman` first argument should be `string filename`.

Comment: Please use a bit less `inline code` highlighting of random words, it really decreases the readability of your question. Anyway try again to greatly reduce the code. Reduce it to the minimal example without external dependencies (i.e. your file which we can't read) that reproduces the issue.

Comment: @CodeCaster Ok thanks, I will take care about it. I have reduces again the code.

Comment: Your code still uses a file we can't see.

Comment: which file you are talking about ? Are you pointing to "args" ? The file taken at sole argument ?

Comment: Yes. Your code errors when processing a file, and we can't see the contents of that file. Please try to create a new, really tiny program that reproduces this issue, without needing a file.

Comment: @CodeCaster I have edited the question, I have made another small program doing same kind of thing. and I have also written how i get this binary file. (Actually it's a binary file i cannot copy and paste here the data but i have written the code for how i obtain this binary file at the end of question in edited part). Thanks for trying to helping me.

Comment: @CodeCaster I have made the question exactly in the way you want it to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the size of the file is not a multitude of 8 bytes (64 bits), the last `ReadBytes()` will result in a `byte[]` smaller than 8 bytes, causing `ToInt64()` to fail.

Comment: last time i was using "Symbol" as "int" type and it was working fine.(int is 4 byte in c#) so, i think the file will read 4 byte each time. So how should i change my code corresponding to that ?

Comment: That is a design problem, not a code problem. The way you've dealt with casting binary data to a generic type would suggest you would be able to grasp that problem as well. How about padding the last `byte[]` with zero bytes to make it fit an `Int64`? It all depends on what you're doing with the result afterwards.